# Best performance for query using "contains" - string or object ref

Tags: performance, search, parse-platform, hashtag

I am implementing a hashtag-based search using Parse. I have an array of hashtags (strings) on the objects I'm searching for and am using query.containedIn to find matches. Works fine.

However, I'm wondering if I should change the array to be an array of Parse Object-refs instead and store the actual hashtags (strings) as separate objects.

PROS:

1. Less space to store refs (In most cases)
2. Faster searches (this is my assumption, and the reason for the question)
3. Can provide lists of known hashtags easily

CONS:

1. Needs an additional query to convert hashtag strings into list of objects before searching (will this eat up the performance gain, assuming there is one?)
2. Needs additional writes (hashtag objects) when updating hashtags

I suspect most objects will not have hashtags, those that do will have maybe a handfull. I have no idea about the number of unique hashtags but for the sake of argument let's assume each tag is used maybe 3 times on average.

Does anyone know if there would be a solid performance gain in switching, or it depends on number and size of hashtags? Or maybe no gain at all?

Any inside info would be much appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around to making a micro-benchmark and figured I'd update this question with my findings, so FWIW:

It seems as if comparing strings is exactly the same as comparing references (which would make sense given that everything is JSON) and thus it has absolutely no effect on query performance how you store these things.

In fact, the JSON representation of an object ref appears to be sufficiently bloated that it might actually save space to just store the string.

Oh well, on to more important issues.